# Close and Abort in custom service channel

Tags: wcf, abort, faulted

My client is using one WCF service which is throwing an exception
(EXCEPTION: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state).
All subsequent calls throwing an same exception.

I read on internet that client need to close()/Abort() channel, this will solve the problem. is it completely right?

Also I am using customer serviceChannel factory provided by service developers. When I create channel it does not show the close and abort methods. So how do I get these close and abort methods when I create custom service channel instance on client side?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make sure you don't get WCF Faulted state exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530731/how-to-make-sure-you-dont-get-wcf-faulted-state-exception)

Comment: It won't fix your problem directly - you cannot reuse a faulted channel (you will have to create a new one after disposing the old one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a proxy instance that implements the IClientChannel interface, here is a way (hopefully the right way) to use it.

```
IClientChannel clientChannel = (IClientChannel)proxy;
bool success = false;

try
{
    // do something with the proxy
    clientChannel.Close();
    success = true;
}
finally
{
    if (!success)
    {
        clientChannel.Abort();
    }
}
```

You may also want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573872/what-is-the-best-workaround-for-the-wcf-client-using-block-issue). You can wrap your operations using a shared class or function.

Comment: ok. I was wondering ,doing this alone on clinet side should solve the problem or some coding also neees to be done at WCF side?