# Getting the System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel in a faulted state error, sometimes

Tags: wpf, wcf

We're recently deployed a major WPF app that has replaced an ancient of days VB6 app (thank God that's gone!) It's been working fine. However this morning one of my users got the "The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state." error message. We encountered this months ago and I looked up the answer here on Stackoverflow, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530731/how-to-make-sure-you-dont-get-wcf-faulted-state-exception). I was careful, from that point forward, to not use the using statement to wrap my WCF services. Nevertheless, this user got this error message. What's worse, when I tried running the app on my development box, using the same data, it worked fine.

So what could be causing this error to occur, sometimes? Both machines are Windows 7 Pro machines; both are 64-bit. Naturally, mind is more powerful, but beyond that I don't think there's much difference.

Comment: First place to start - [Enable WCF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  As Deeppansh Gupta indicates in his answer, an unhandled exception will fault the channel.  The trace logs will help you find that exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WCF, exception occuring at the service side and not being handled through FaultContract would put the communication channel between the service and the client aka proxy in the Faulted State. Hence please check if some exception is occuring at the service side.

Comment: Deepansh, is enabling WCF tracing the only way to determine what exceptions have occurred on the server?

Comment: If proper logging is implemented in the server, server logs should be capturing the exceptions.